# Setting $XDG_CONFIG_HOME

Tags: vimrc, neovim

My current `nvim` is in `~/AppData/Local/` and I want to drag it out just one directory below `$HOME`. How can I set `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, and can it be done via Neovim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting environment variables is done via the OS or the shell.

On Windows, you can [use the GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17312376/152142)

> Right click on Computer, Advanced system settings, select Advanced tab and click Environment variables.

or [use the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898197/152142) (cmd.exe):

```
setx XDG_CONFIG_HOME C:\Users\foo\bar
```

- **Note:** `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is generic to all XDG-compliant applications, so don't set it to an Nvim-specific path. If you set `XDG_CONFIG_HOME=C:\Users\foo`, then Nvim will put its config in `C:\Users\foo\nvim`, and other apps will put their configs in `C:\Users\foo\<app>`.

  - `:help xdg` attempts to explain this clearly.

Comment: Thanks! If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is set, would it cause problems or changes to other applications?

Comment: No, its entire purpose is to tell XDG-compliant applications where to put their configs. Note that `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` should not be Nvim-specific. If you  set `XDG_CONFIG_HOME=foo`, then Nvim puts its config in `foo/nvim`, and other apps will put their configs in `foo/<app>`.